# How to show a message with C# in a WebForm

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need to show a message in my aspx page using C# language when the condition i wrote isn't true int the html form 
anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute simplest and dirtiest way is:-

```
// YourCondition defined as public property of the .aspx page
<% if ( YourCondition != true ) { %>
Your conditional text.
<% } %>
```

Comment: and what if "YourCondition" appers in the PageLoad Paragraph?
it says:The name 'dtusers' does not exist in the current context when dtusers is my "YourCondition"

Comment: Yeah, I actually intended for you to replace the YourCondition bit with a boolean expression evaluating to true.  Apologies for not making that clear.

Answer (score 2):

In your ASPX:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="conditionalLabel" visible="false" />
```

In your code-behind:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if(!conditionToCheck)
    {
        conditionalLabel.Visible = true;
        conditionalLabel.Text = "This is my label text";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Andrew's solution is more elegant, but if you're feeling hackish there is a slightly simpler way. The disadvantage is that this method lacks control over where the message is placed. It will show up between whatever html had already been buffered/emitted at the time the check is made:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if(!conditionToCheck)
    {
        Response.Write("You messed up!");
    }
}
```